# Is there an elegant way to process multi futures within the specified timeout period?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Mycodes are as follows: the two try...catch blocks are so ugly.

i have two requests, if one responses within timeout period i will add it to the list, if not i will add a null to the list instead.

```
private List<String> getResult(Future future1, Future future2, long timeout) {
    String resp1= null;
    String resp2= null;
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();

    try {
        resp1= future1.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("req1 error", e);
    }
    //  calculate the time remaining
    long leftTime = timeout - stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (leftTime > 0) {
        try {
            resp2 = future2.get(leftTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("req2 error", e);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> results = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(2);
    results.add(resp1);
    results.add(resp2);
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't too much you could do; besides eliminating the code duplication; by simply moving that code into its own method, like:

```
private String getResultFromFuture(Future future, long timeout, String message) {
  try {
    return future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(message, e);
  }
  return null;
}
```

or something alike; for example by also providing a list to which the result is added; instead of returning it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this and call it for two Future objects.

```
    public void process(Future<String> f, int timeout, List<String> list) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
                try{
                    list.add(f.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                }catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    // add what you want
                }


}
```